# Javascript Image Animation does not work in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, image, animation

I am using the following script to generate an animation of images.

It works in Chrome but not Firefox or Internet Explorer ...

Javascript

```
var lista = new Array('image1.gif','image1.gif','image1.gif','image1.gif'); 
var tiempo = 500; 
var tempor = null; 
var pos=0; 
var i = 0; 

function boucle_images(){ 
        var nombre_total_images = 6; 
        document.images.centro.src = lista[i] 
        pos=i; 
        i++; 
        i%=nombre_total_images; 
        tempor=setTimeout("boucle_images()",tiempo); 

} 

function avanza(){ 

  if (pos==(lista.length-1)) 
      pos=0; 
  else 
  pos++; 
  document.images.centro.src = lista[pos] 

} 

function retroceso(){ 

  if (pos==0) 
      pos=(lista.length-1); 
  else 
  pos--; 
  document.images.centro.src = lista[pos] 
} 

function automat(){ 
tempor = setTimeout("boucle_images()", tiempo) 
} 

function parar(){ 
clearTimeout(tempor); 
}
```

HTML

```
<table width="52%" border="0" align="center"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td height="482" colspan="2" align="right">
                        <img id="centro" src="imagenes/cargando2.gif" alt="" width="640" height="480" /></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td align="center"><div class="div_ani_sat">
                        <a href="javascript:retroceso()"><img src="imagenes/atras.png" width="48" height="48" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="javascript:avanza()"><img src="imagenes/adelante.png" width="48" height="48" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="javascript:boucle_images()"><img src="imagenes/play.png" width="48" height="48" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="javascript:parar()"><img src="imagenes/pause.png" width="48" height="48" alt="" /></a></div>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table>
```

Not that I can not function in other browsers ...
Can you help?
thanks

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById('centro').src` instead `document.images.centro` Coz `document.images` returns a `HTML Collection` I really wonder how does `document.images.id` works for you. Might be some chrome optimization. Don't trust it across browsers

Comment: I made ​​the switch, but still the same.

Comment: Actually what happens? Are you able to see any javascript error in the console? Try F12 in chrome and ie. If there is no error then plz mention also what difference you are able to see btwn chrome and firefox

Comment: What happens is that the animation does not occur in Firefox and Internet Explorer. The console shows no error.

Comment: have assigned a fiddle of the same code of yours but with small fixes. Have increased the delay to 5S but

Comment: Are you still facing some issue?

Comment: You have the same image filename in the array of images.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/wtpHC/) is a working version of your same code tested in chrome + firefox

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) Accepts the first argument as reference to a function. So, I just replaced your `tempor=setTimeout("boucle_images()",tiempo)` to `tempor=setTimeout(boucle_images, tiempo)`. Always follow this coz it saves an eval

`document.images`  returns a `HTML Collection` which you can access like an array [but it is not an array] but not like `document.image.centros` [atleast across browsers] Hence I fixed it to `document.getElementById('centros')`

Comment: @Bcl00 Are you still facing some issue?

Comment: Definitely with all the solutions do not get it to work in all browsers. Seeketh otherwise. Thanks to the suguerencias. a Greeting